# iOS VoiceOver Button not Calling Target Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, accessibility, voiceover

I have a UIButton subclass, ACTLanguageButton that really just does some custom UI changes so that I can reuse the style. In the subclass I have the following code relating to the accessibility:

```
- (BOOL)isAccessibilityElement {
    return YES;
}

- (NSString *)accessibilityLabel {
    NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:self.language];
    NSString *displayLanguage = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:self.language];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Language Preference: %@", displayLanguage];
}

- (NSString *)accessibilityHint {
    return @"Opens the list of available languages for accessible services.";
}

- (UIAccessibilityTraits)accessibilityTraits {
    return UIAccessibilityTraitButton;
}
```

And in the UIView that instantiates and is the superview of the ACTLanguage Button:

```
self.languageButton = [[ACTLanguageButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - 120, 20, 120, 25)];
[self addSubview:self.languageButton];
[self.languageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onLanguages) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And then the method "onLanguages" itself which just shows a popup view that appears modally over the UIView:

```
- (void)onLanguages {
    [self.languagePopupView showWithCallback:nil];
}
```

The button action works perfectly without VoiceOver enabled (normal tap-to-use). In addition, when I use the Accessibility Inspector on OS X with a simulator, the action gets performed just fine as well.

On a real device (testing on an iPhone 5 running 9.3), the "onLanguages" method never gets called. The accessibility label, hint, and traits are read correctly, I can focus the element just fine, but the double-tap doesn't trigger the "onLanguages" method as expected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The foolproof way to get this working is to implement [`acccessibilityActivate()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615165-accessibilityactivate) and invoke `onLanguages()` from there.

Comment: This was brilliant. I overrode it just to call [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; and it worked right away. Thanks so much!